# Getting IllegalStateException from Log4j when deserializating JMS ObjectMessage

Tags: java, serialization, log4j, deserialization, log4j2

I have an application that send a log message over to JMS (ActiveMQ) and a process that consumes the log message puts to a database. It worked with log4j 1.x. After upgrading to log4j2, with the same version of ActiveMQ (compiled and runtime both Java 8). I can see the messages in the Topic but during deserialization in the consumer throws the following exception. The same compiled versions of classes are deployed on both producer and consumer.

Please help!

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: readObject requires a FilteredObjectInputStream or an ObjectInputStream that accepts an ObjectInputFilter
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SortedArrayStringMap.readObject(SortedArrayStringMap.java:591)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1185)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2236)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1692)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2378)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2236)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1692)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2378)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2236)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1692)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:508)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:466)
    **at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:177)**
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.toString(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:199)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:137)
    **at com.abc.common.jms.JMSConsumer.onMessage(JMSConsumer.java:106)**
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1021)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:192)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Using JMS `ObjectMessage` is actively discouraged for reasons like this, although the main reason it is discouraged is due to security concerns. I encourage you to leverage a different serialization technology (e.g. JSON) if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

FilteredObjectInputStream is a class in Log4j-api. You would need that in your ActiveMQ classpath to be able to deserialize in Java 8. In Java 9 or greater you don't need the FilteredObjectInputStream because Log4jLogEvent will call setObjectInputFilter on the ObjectInputStream to perform the same security checks.

Note that the Log4j team STRONGLY recommends not using Java serialization. You should consider it deprecated and likely to be removed in Log4j 3.x

Comment: The log4j-api-2.17.1.jar (the version of log4j2 I am using) is in the classpath and so is its core jar, but still it fails. I copied both the jars under ACTIVE_MQ/lib directory. 

This error is thrown in the JMS Consumer application, that has the two jars in the classpath as well. What I observe is the JMS producer works fine as I see increasing number of messages in ActiveMQ, it is when it deserializes it in the consumer. The only way I could make it work is to change the runtime to Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

Found out log4j2 has been changed vis-a-vis serialization/deserializtion to be compatible with Java9. Changed the runtime env to be Java9 and it worked.

Is there any way it can be run with Java 8?

Comment: It is not about compatibility (Java 8 and Java 9 have the same serialization format), but about security: Log4j2 uses a Java 9 feature, that allows you to restrict the kind of objects that are deserialized. This prevents remote code injections.